# Can we train Tensorflow custom object Detection model in SageMaker of AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, object-detection-api, amazon-sagemaker

Could you just help me with the following points:

1. Can we train the tensorflow custom object detection model in SageMaker of AWS?
2. I came across SageMaker's Image classification Algorithm? Can we use it to detect particular objects in Video after training the model?
3. Confused with the pricing plan of SageMaker. They are saying "you are offered a monthly free tier of 250 hours of t2.medium notebook usage"; Does that mean we can use t2.medium notebook free for 250 hours?

Final AIM is to train a model for custom object detection like we used to train in paperspace or floydhub in very less price.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

1- Sure. You can bring any TensorFlow code to SageMaker. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/tf-examples.html

2- This is a classification model (labels only), not a detection model (labels + bounding boxes). Having said that, yes, you can definitely use it to predict frames extracted from a video.

3- Yes, in the first 12 months following the creation of your AWS account.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Any TensorFlow model can be used/ported to SageMaker. You can find examples of TensorFlow models ported to SageMaker here https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/master/sagemaker-python-sdk#amazon-sagemaker-examples.